# Why does my if statement only get called once despite being called with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In this example the updateLive function is being called every second, however the 'if' statement within, seems to only be called 3 times rather than every second.

There are 3 objects in the array with duration = 'N/A', so it seems like the logging statement is executing correctly in that regard, but I'm not sure why it does not continue executing every second.

```
 methods: {
    updateLive: function() {
      for (let item = 0; item < this.jobs.length; item++) {
        console.log('this prints every second')
         if (this.jobs[item].duration == "N/A") {
          console.log("This only gets called 3 times")
           this.liveDuration(this.jobs[item], this.jobs[item].time_start)
    }
  }
},
},
  mounted() {
    let that=this;
    setInterval(function() { that.updateLive()}, 1000);
  },
```

Why is this happening and how do I work around it?

Comment: You don't need to pass `this` to `that`: `mounted(){setInterval(this.updateLive, 1000)}`

Comment: Have you tried logging out the value of `this.jobs[item].duration`? I would imagine it starts off as `'N/A'` but gets changed to something else, possibly inside `liveDuration`.

Comment: You've got a typo, a bracket is not closed. Please edit your question so as to include a correct code.

Comment: wow I'm an idiot, thank you @skirtle